# Prove $Y$ is closed in $X$ given that $(X, d)$ is a metric space and $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ such that the induced metric is the discrete metric.

Tags: general-topology

So far I have:

Since no point $P$ is a limit point of any set except $\{P\}$ with the discrete metric, therefore any given set that is part of $Y$ contains all its limit points, and hence $Y$ itself contains all its own limit points.

Is that all i need or do i need to add something else?

Answer (score 2):

Your argument concerns the limit points of sets considered as subsets of $Y$ under the induced topology.  This is not at all the same as considering the limit points of sets considered as subsets of $X$ under the original topology.  In the former sense $Y$ is closed in itself for trivial reasons, and what you are trying to prove is instead the latter sense.

The result as stated is furthermore false if you replace "induced metric is the discrete metric" with "induced metric is equivalent to the discrete metric".  Consider $X = \Bbb R, Y = \{1/n: n\in \Bbb N\}$.  The set $Y$ is not closed because $0$ is a limit point.  The induced metric is also discrete since $Y \cap \left(\frac{1}{n+1/2}, \frac{1}{n-1/2}\right) = \{1/n\}$ holds for all $n$.

This example demonstrates that you need to utilize the specific hypothesis that $d(y_1, y_2) = 1$ for all distinct $y_1, y_2 \in Y$.  With this assumption, you should be able to show directly that any $x\in X \setminus Y$ has an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood disjoint from $Y$.